# What is the relationship between the 99% Line and throughput in Jmeter's Aggregate Report

Tags: testing, jmeter

I ran a jmeter test case where I found :-

Samples - 26133 
99% Line to be - 2061ms 
ThroughPut - 43.6/s

My question is how can the throughput be 43.6 requests per second when then 99% Line is showing at 2061ms. From my understanding that means 99% of the samples took NO MORE THAN this time. The 1% remaining samples took at least as long as this.
So Shouldn't the throughput be less than 1 request per second? How is it able to serve 46 requests per second when 99% itself take 2 seconds to respond?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- 99% is response time
- Throughput is the number of requests for the test duration

Given the number of samplers and the throughput my expectation is that you ran your test for 10 minutes.

If you would execute your test with 1 user having response time of 2 seconds for 10 minutes you would get 300 samples. Looking at the numbers I can assume that you had something like 87 users.

And this 87 users (or whatever is your number) is a key point because throughput indicates **concurrency**

- 1 user which executes 1 request each 2 seconds - throughput will be 0.5 hits per second
- 2 users which execute 1 request each 2 seconds - throughput will be 1 hit per second
- 4 users which execute 1 request each 2 seconds - throughput will be 2 hits per second
- etc.

More information:

- [JMeter Glossary](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html)
- [What is the Relationship Between Users and Hits Per Second?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-relationship-between-users-and-hits-second)